# Can you dynamically set an attribute in a Powershell cmdlet call?

Tags: powershell, parameters, powershell-cmdlet

I am not sure if this is possible, but I am wondering if there's an elegant "dynamic" way to use or not an attribute when using a cmdlet in Powershell.

For instance, in the code below, how can i set the `-directory` attribute to be present or not, depending on some conditions?

```
gci $folder_root -recurse -directory | ForEach{ 
  # do something
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can conditionally add parameter arguments to a call through a technique called [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.2).

All you need to do is construct a dictionary-like object and add any parameters you might want to pass to the call there:

```
# Create empty hashtable to hold conditional arguments
$optionalArguments = @{}

# Conditionally add an argument
if($somethingThatMightBeTrue){
    # This is equivalent to having the `-Directory` switch present
    $optionalArguments['Directory'] = $true
}

# And invoke the command
Get-ChildItem $folder_root -Recurse @optionalArguments
```

Notice that any variable that we *splat* is specified with a `@` instead of `$` at the call site.